# Simple protractor test for isElementPresent failing with unsupported locator strategy

Tags: angularjs, mocha.js, protractor

My test:

```
it('should allow login', function() {
  browser.get('index.html');

  $('#username').sendKeys('administrator');
  $('#password').sendKeys('password');
  $('#login').click();

  var logout = $('#logout');
  expect($p.isElementPresent(logout)).to.eventually.be.true;
});
```

But this errors out with:

```
Error: Unsupported locator strategy: click
  at Error (<anonymous>)
  at Function.webdriver.Locator.createFromObj (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/locators.js:97:9)
  at Function.webdriver.Locator.checkLocator (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/locators.js:111:33)
  at webdriver.WebDriver.findElements (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:805:31)
  at webdriver.WebDriver.isElementPresent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js:787:29)
  at Protractor.isElementPresent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/protractor.js:476:22)
  at /Users/pschuegr/wt/client/e2e/login_test.js:26:15
```

Strangely, it points to the isElementPresent line, rather than the line with the click.  I'm pretty new to webdriver, so apologies if I missed something obvious.  I'm running using the mocha framework (which means the canary version of protractor), fwiw.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: What is $p and where is it coming from?

Comment: $p is the protractor instance (ie ptor)

Comment: now `$p` and `ptor` have been effectively replaced by `browser`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('#logout')` is a WebElement.  `isElementPresent` takes a locator, like by.css

```
$('#username').sendKeys('administrator');
$('#password').sendKeys('password');
$('#login').click();

var logout = by.css('#logout');
browser.wait(function() { return $p.isElementPresent(logout); }, 8000);
expect($p.isElementPresent(logout)).toBeTruthy();
```

Answer (score 17):

Using the latest Protractor build, you can shorten the above answer to the following:

```
expect(element(by.css('#logout')).isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
```

This way you do not have to perform the browser.wait and you reduce the number of calls to isElementPresent.

Comment: Where does the wait happen here, and why? I don't see why any of your changes would render the `browser.wait` call unnecessary, so I assume there's been a change within protractor that has made this possible without the explicit wait? If so, what's that change?

Comment: @MarkAmery To me it seems there hasn't been, this might work for elements that are already available rather than ones you're waiting for.

Comment: @MarkAmery protractor uses promises in all it's functions, and also waits for $http requests to be completed (if any) before resolving. So with the answer here, the expectation will 1) get the element 2) when that's resolved, it will check whether the element is present 3) When that's resolved, the expectation for a truthy result will be triggered. The wait happens under the hood, you do not need to manually wait, each promise in step 1, 2 and 3 will take care of waiting as needed for each promise to be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The safest approach I would take is depicted in the following code snippet:

```
it('should return true when element is present', function () {
 var logout;
 logout = $('#logout');

  browser.driver.isElementPresent(logout).then(function (isPresent) {
    isPresent = (isPresent) ? true : browser.wait(function () {
      return browser.driver.isElementPresent(logout );
    }, 15000); //timeout after 15s 
    expect(isPresent).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Above code starts of with a promise to check if an element exists, and if true then assign it `true`, otherwise wait and keep pooling for the next 15sec to see if element is present, and in both cases we expect it to be true.

Answer (score -1):

This should work :

```
var logout = $('#logout');
expect(logout.isPresent()).to.eventually.be.true;
```

Comment: isPresent() does not return a promise, so you cannot use 'eventually'!
I've had made the same mistake... -.-

Comment: Thx @Sentenza this comment was helpful.