# How to check if an element doesnt exist selenium nodejs

Tags: node.js, selenium, mocha.js

I want to check if an element exists on the page(which shouldnt) and continue if it doesnt.

```
driver.wait(function() {   
        fieldBool = driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.id("someId"));
        return fieldBool;
}, timeout).then(function(b) {
        assert.equal(false, b, "message");    
});
```

I want fieldBool to be false, but the test stops(timeout or no such element exists).

Comment: I found this example:  `expect(element(by.css('#logout')).isPresent()).toBeTruthy();`.  You can review the item here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245418/simple-protractor-test-for-iselementpresent-failing-with-unsupported-locator-str

Comment: So i should use `toBeFalsy()` ?

Answer (score 5):

The WebDriver will throw an error when an element does not exist. So, we have to check for the `NoSuchElementError`.

We can check that an element does not exist by making use of the optional callbacks for the `.findElement` promise `driver.findElement(...).then(successCallback,errorCallback)` which will get called as the parameter names imply.

The following is how I've been doing it:

```
var existed = await driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id("someId")).then(function() {
    return true;//it was found
}, function(err) {
    if (err instanceof webdriver.error.NoSuchElementError) {
        return false;//element did not exist
    } else {
        webdriver.promise.rejected(err);//some other error...
    }
});
assert.equal(existed,false,"message");
```

Comment: I don't know about all the magix in the webdriver.promise world, but man is it difficult to find out how to see if element exists! .then(success, fail)! that's all! THANK YOU ARTHUR WEBORG

Comment: Happy to be of assistance, really glad to hear my digging helped someone else out! (2 days on and off haha) agreed on the difficulty >_< too bad the method from the original answer was deprecated, looked much simpler!

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.findElements(webdriver.By.id('someId')).then((elements)=>{
   if(elements.length > 0){
     throw new Error('The Element was found!');
   } else {
     return true;
   }
});
```

This works by finding all of the elements that match the id, css, name etc, and making sure that the result that comes back (which would be an array of elements) has a length of 0 - meaning no elements were found with that css/id/name etc on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
driver.isElementPresent(webdriver.By.id("someId")).then(
    function(isPresent){
        assert.equal(false, isPresent , "message");   
    }
)
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: `.isElementPresent(...)` doesn't appear to be a method according to the [nodejs spec for the webDriver](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebDriver.html). is `driver` here from the standard npm package (selenium-webdriver)?

Comment: .isElementPresent is deprecated